# C# Progressbar won't update with backgroundworker

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

I am trying to update my progressbar with the backgroundworker. Only this aint working. Here's my code:

```
private BackgroundWorker _worker;

public Form1(string[] args)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // Backgroundworker to update the progressbar
    _worker = new BackgroundWorker();
    _worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    _worker.ProgressChanged += worker_ProgressChanged;
    _worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
    _worker.RunWorkerCompleted += worker_WorkCompleted;

}

private void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    SendItems();
}
private void worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
}
private void worker_WorkCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    _running = false;
    HandleGui();
}

private bool SendItems()
{
    try
    {
        GetEvaluationDocumentsToSend();
        _worker.ReportProgress(16);

        GetModifiedEvaluationDocumentsToSend();
        _worker.ReportProgress(32);

        GetTasksToSend();
        _worker.ReportProgress(48);

        GetPostToSend();
        _worker.ReportProgress(64);

        GetContractDocumentsToSend();
        _worker.ReportProgress(80);

        GetModifiedContractDocumentsToSend();
        _worker.ReportProgress(100);

        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.WriteLog(e.ToString());

        MessageBox.Show(
            "The following error occured while sending the items: \r\n" + e.ToString(),
            "Error",
            MessageBoxButtons.OK,
            MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);

        return false;
    }
}

private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _worker.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

I don't get any errors, but my progressbar will not update. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does the ProgressChanged event actually fire?

Comment: Yes. When I set a breakpoint on the method call and the progressChanged event than first the method is executed and then the progressChanged event.

Comment: I've tested your code and it works fine. Do you have anything else setting the progress bar value? Also, what are the min and max values for your progress bar?

Comment: I've replaced some code that sets my progressbar.value to 0. Don't know exaclty what I've done and what went wrong, but it is working fine now.

Comment: Make sure your progressbar.MinimumValue = 0 and progressbar.MaximumValue = 100 and the progressbar.Value is initially set to 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well it works on my machine. What does `GetEvaluationDocumentsToSend()` do? Perhaps it is taking a lot longer than the other methods so it looks like no progress is made because all of the progress is almost instantaneous? Also, what does `HandleGui()` do and what is `_running` used for?

Answer (score 2):

You didn't start the BackgroundWorker !

Add this line after event subscriptions :

```
_worker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

EDIT : 
Now the code shows that you call the RunWorkerAsync()

Try to add Thread.Sleep(1000) after each progress to see if your process is too fast...

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to mention that in my code. I will update my startpost.

Answer (score 0):

try adding a Invoke/BeingInvoke call around your progressbar update:

```
this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
{
    progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
});
```

This is usually the reason UI's are not getting updated.

Comment: The entire point of the background worker is that it takes care of that.

Comment: CAUTION   Always call EndInvoke after your asynchronous call completes.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e08f6yc%28VS.71%29.aspx

Comment: Fair point. I would still do it as a matter of habit. In this case, I can't work out why his code doesn't work, so I'm just providing a posibility.